# AngularJS: pass variable to modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use https://github.com/simpulton/angularjs-wizard for my project, it works,
(I modified it a little, replaced `var app` to `$scope`)

but I need to pass a variable to `open` function:

```
$scope.open = function (image)
    {
        $scope.image = image;

        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'wizard.html',
            controllerAs: 'modal',
            size: 'lg',
            controller: 'ModalCtrl',
            resolve: {
                image: function () {
                    return image;
                }
            }
        });

        modalInstance.result
            .then(function (data) {
                $scope.closeAlert();
                $scope.summary = data;
            }, function (reason) {
                $scope.reason = reason;
            });
    };
```

and in html:

```
ng-click="open(image)"
```

but `image` is `undefined` in my template

it works if I only just the modal window, with the example from https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal,
but not with this wizard example

**update:**

https://jsfiddle.net/Ginstay/znz64sk3/2/

yes, ajax is completed at the moment, when I open the modal window

and if I add a breakpoint to `return image;` image is there

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle? It's hard to catch where problem is/

Comment: Try passing an image url in ng-click="open('http://urlofimage.com')"

Comment: it's not an url, it's an object, retrieved with ajax request
because of the same reason, I'm not how I can make a jsfiddle, but I'll try now

Comment: could you please add `ModalCtrl` code?

Comment: @lasoweq is your image already retrieved by an ajax request when you try to open the modal? The AJAX might still not be processed.

Comment: How do you expect to use your image scope variable when it is defined and assigned only after calling the `open` function? Of course it is undefined and can never work.

Comment: I updated the question with jsfiddle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try this one**

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal) {

var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
  resolve: {
    test: function () {
      return 'test variable';
    }
  }
});
};

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, test) {
  $scope.test = test;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it, I needed to add

```
$scope.image = image;
```

to `ModalCtrl`